# Jquery - clicking the button loads the html in one div but makes the other div invisible

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am new to Jquery. I have 3 divs, the first div is the header, the second div contains slide show images along with the button and the third div is displayed when a button is clicked. This third div is loaded with external HTML file. When the third div is loaded after clicking the button, the second div is not visible. Please, help me out. The problem is shown in the image below
[screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDr1e.jpg)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIOrN.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="MainScreen.css">
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="MainScreenJavaScript.js"></script>
<script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<style>
     body{
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
         }
</style>


</head>
<body>

<!-- Navbar top -->
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#home" class="colors" >HOME</a>
<a href="Resume.html"  class="colors" >ABOUT</a>
<a href="contact.html" class="colors" >CONTACT</a>
<a href="#icon" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<!--Slide show -->
<div class="slideshow-container ">
   <div class="mySlides fade">
   <img src="laptop.jpg" class="image">
   <div class="text">Keen to learn many things</div>
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="travel2.jpg" class="image">
   <div class="text">Like to travel</div>
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="education.jpg" class="image">
  <div class="text">Education and Background</div>
 </div>

 <div class="mySlides fade">
  <img src="cook1.jpg" class="image">
  <div class="text" >
    <button id="cookButton" onclick="loadExternalHtml()">Love for 
        Cooking</button>
  </div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
  <!-- dots-->
  <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
   </div>

   <div id="content"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     var slideIndex =1;
      showSlides(slideIndex);

      function loadExternalHtml(){
          $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#cookButton").click(function(){
             $("#content").load("foodBlog.html"); //load html page onclicking the button

      });

    });
   }


  </script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Here is my foodBlog.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/
    bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
 </script>
   </head>

   <body>

  <div class="container" >
       <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="text.jpg" class="img-rounded"  alt="text" 
   style="width:100%;height:250px">
   <h3>text</h3>
   <p>It is a street food</p>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 ">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="text1.jpg" class="img-rounded"  alt="text1" 
    style="width:100%;height:250px;">
  <h3>text1</h3>
   <p>text1</p>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="text2.jpg" class="img-rounded"  alt="text1" 
     style="width:100%;height:250px;">
    <h3>text2</h3>
     <p>text2</p>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's inside `foodBlog.html`?

Comment: I have 3 divs in a row which include images with text. I am using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

is a child of `slideshow-container` and behavior depend of CSS for `content` and `slideshow-container`. What will You see when You will move `content` outside `slideshow-container` ?

Also try: `float:left;` or `overflow:hidden;` for `content`

More important than HTML and jQuery script is CSS that You use for this ID's and classes.

Comment: content is outside slideshow-container. I tried using overflow:hidden and float:left. But no difference.

Comment: please, help me. I observe the HTML file which I'm loading is with bootstrap. Maybe because of that the slideshow div with images is not visible.

Comment: if You do not include bootstrap.css then class name doesn't have impact on Your CSS ... also we can only guess what can be wrong without see it live. Put it on some server and show, maybe then someone will help.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your reply. How do I that? I haven't done it before. If you guide me it would be of great help.

Comment: when I run the file, I will get this error. **jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///E:/complete%20web%20developer%20course/rashmirangaswamaiah/foodBlog.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https**. So, I made use of 200 ok webserver, in order to load external html file into div.